# radio buttons not working on touchable devices

Tags: android, html, css, radio-button

So far i have built this radio buttons style but they don't work on touchable devices.I have only tested them on android but i assume they won't work on any touch device.Any idea what am i doing wrong?
The entire example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/rpx6hwzx/
Here's my html  code:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <div class="switch">
        <input type="radio" class="switch-input switch-input-on" name="radio" value="1" id="radio-on" checked="checked"> 
        <label for="radio-on" class="switch-label switch-label-on">On</label>

        <input type="radio" class="switch-input switch-input-off" name="radio" value="0" id="radio-off"> 
        <label for="radio-off" class="switch-label switch-label-off">Off</label>
        <span class="switch-selection"></span>        
    </div>    
</form>
```

Thanks.

Edit:
After some searches it seems that targeting the elements this way is not supported on android:

`switch-input:checked + .switch-label-off ~ .switch-selection:before`

Any alternative?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work on touch devices ? Is it only the look&feel, or the functionality self ? I mean, is the proper radio button selected but not showing as selected, or doesn't it work at all ?

Comment: Only the switch effect is not working.

Comment: The effect works fine on Windows Phone (just tested the jsfiddle on a Lumia). Could it be the version of Android?

Comment: Great..But what about for a fix for android (and probably for ios too)? How should i target this touch event?

Comment: Just did a test on browserstack and it seems only on android is not working.

Comment: Wild guess: Could it be caused by the lack of `/` in the `input` tags?

Comment: No :) ,only in the XHTML the input must be closed like this <input />

Comment: How about simplifying the problematic selector and see if it works? Remove the + and the ~ and test `switch-input:checked .switch-label-off .switch-selection:before`

Answer (score 0):

That's a great way to style a form functionally only using CSS. Just tested on Chrome/Android 4.4 and the original fiddle worked just fine, but indeed the selector could be more simple. Since you want to change the `.switch-input:checked + .switch-label-off` to `.switch-input-off:checked`. It would be like this:

```
.switch-input-off:checked ~ .switch-selection:before {
```